# Few confusing things about factories in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

a) I'm a bit puzzled whether in most cases we should only have a factory that produces the *entire Aggregate* or should we also have a factory that creates only the *Aggregate root*?

b) Should a factory that builds the *entire Aggregate* build both *root* and *non-root* objects by itself or should it delegate the building of *non-root* entities/VOs to other factories?

Thus, if *Aggregate* contains 5 different types of *non-root entities*, should *Aggregate factory* create these *non-root entities* by itself or should we have additional five *factories* ( one factory for each non-root entity ), to which *Aggregate factory* would delegate the creation of particular type of *non-root entity*?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Eric Evans' DDD book, page 138, it's written in bold:

> **Create entire aggregates as a piece, enforcing their invariants.**

Then in the next page:

> A FACTORY should only be able to produce an object in a consistent
>   state. For an ENTITY, this means the creation of the entire AGGREGATE
>   [...]

Concretely, this means that you would only have one factory to create the entire aggregate. There *may* be other classes (factories) involved in building your non-root entities or value objects, but there is only one factory responsible for creating an aggregate. This factory creates a full aggregate, not just a root object.

Comment: What is the reasoning against having factories dedicated to a particular type ( and to which Aggregate factory would delegate the creation of particular type ), especially considering that quite often we may want to add elements inside preexisting Aggregates, in which case we must create factories for creating non-root objects?

Comment: @user437291: I suppose you could have a factory for a non-root object, but the factory for your root object should still create a complete and valid aggregate. It doesn't make sense to have a factory which creates ONLY a root, but it might create the non-root objects with the help of other classes/factories.

Comment: But I assume the point you're also making is that having the work of creating an entire aggregate divided among several factories ( as opposed to a single factory doing all of the object creation ) doesn't bring any benefits?

Comment: @user437291: If you need to "add elements into preexisting Aggregates" as you mentioned, and building those elements is complex, then I suppose a factory for this object could bring some benefits. But by default I would go with a single factory for each aggregate.

Comment: Could I ask if this means that the `non-root` can have their factory methods and used by the `AR` in the process of creating of the entire AGGREGATE? And if the answer is yes then how to prevent the client code or other aggregates from misusing  non-root` factory methods !

Answer (score 3):

The creation of sub-root objects (for example, an `OrderItem` for an `Order`) is handled by the root entity itself, so it can enforce variants in a manner invisible to the outside world.

So a typical flow could be:

```
var newOrder = orderFactory.CreateOrder(customer);

newOrder.AddOrderItem(product, quantity);
```

A factory might be used within the entity, but it shouldn't be accessed by the outside world.

```
public class Order
{
     private OrderItemFactory _orderItemFactory;

     public AddOrderItem(Product product, int Quantity)
     {
          var newOrderItem = _orderItemFactory.CreateOrderItem(product, quantity);
     }
}`
```

Comment: "A factory might be used within the entity, but it shouldn't be accessed by the outside world." So under no circumstances should a non-root factory be implemented as a Service?

Comment: A factory isn't a service, it's a factory.  Services handle interactions between entities (including interactions with the outside world), while factories abstract out instantiation.  You might find that your non-root object is needed to be created outside the root - in that case you need to look at your model.  Either the subobject isn't really in the root, or you should be going through the root.

Comment: "A factory isn't a service, it's a factory." But according to Evans, if needed, factory can also be implemented as a Service - in which case factory is a Service?!

Comment: What part of the Evans book are you referring to?  A factory is an object which encapsulates object instantiation, and allows alternative implementations to be easily substituted.   While a Service might instantiate objects, it should properly defer that to a factory internally to not violate the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: Could I ask if `OrderItem` has its own factory method and used in the root factory method ? and how we prevent the client code from misusing the factory methods in non-root aggregates in that case?

Comment: The non-aggregate root object should not be created outside of the aggregate root, IMHO.  Can you have an OrderItem without an order?  No - so order.AddNewItem makes much more sense for encapsulation. 

The alternative - 

orderItem = orderItemFactory.Create()
order.AddItem(orderItem)

exposes details of how an item is added the outside world doesn't need to know.  What happens when new logic is added?

This, btw, is a major reason NOT to use ORM objects as DDD entites, but treat them as DTOs.  They'll often require public construction when that doesn't make sense in the business.